# node.js server not responding, and not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm pretty new to node and I'm trying to create a simple server for iOS notes app but when I type in node server.js in command prompt nothing happens.

`

```
//CREATE A NOTE
//Post request
app.post("/create", (req, res) => {

    var Note = new Data({

        note: req.get("note"),
        title: req.get("title"),
        date: req.get("data"),
    })

    note.save().then(() => {
        if (note.isNew == false){
            console.log("Save data!")
            res.send("Saved data")
        }else {
            console.log("Failed to save data")
        }
    })
})

// http://10.11.210.1:8081/create
var server = app.listen(8081, "10.11.210.1", function(){
    console.log("Server is running!")
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fII4J.png)

Comment: Why are you storing app.listen() output in `server` in var and if you want to make sure to call it or better just don't store.

Comment: is it express.js?

Comment: What is `app` ?

Comment: Remove that explicit IP address, Express doesn't need it except under _very_ special conditions. Also @SadikSaifi you store the server in a variable so that you can shut down the server in code. That should of course be a `const`, not a `var` , but capturing the server in a variable is pretty normal.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

```js
/ import express (after npm install express)
const express = require('express');

// create new express app and save it as "app"
const app = express();

// server configuration
const PORT = 8080;

// create a route for the app
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

//Post request
app.post("/create", (req, res) => {

  var Note = new Data({

    note: req.get("note"),
    title: req.get("title"),
    date: req.get("data"),
  })

  note.save().then(() => {
    if (note.isNew == false) {
      console.log("Save data!")
      res.send("Saved data")
    } else {
      console.log("Failed to save data")
    }
  })
})

// make the server listen to requests
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at: http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```